# How can I retrieve Basic Authentication credentials from the header in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone explain to me how to get a username and password from a request header in ruby?

While communicating with another system, before I was sending the user name and password and now I have changed the user name and password in both the system. But still, I'm getting **#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>** error

Comment: Are you really still on Ruby on Rails 3 (which is about 10 years old)? I am asking because old Rails versions might demand much different answers than more recent versions.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the username and password? Do you want to use them to secure your application with basic auth? Hint: that is already built-in into Rails? Or do you need to do something other with it like storing it into database etc?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one `request.headers`

E.g
`request.headers['username']`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do so is to access `request.headers`

```rb
request.headers[:password]
# or
request.headers['password']
```

If you're unsure about the headers you're sending/receiving you can always do

```rb
raise request.headers.inspect
```